# Why i'm i getting the wrong day of the week for a certain date?

Tags: java, date, calendar, simpledateformat

I'm trying to get the day of the week that corresponds to a date.
I'm using **Java's Calendar** **and** **SimpleDateFormat**.

But i'm getting the wrong outputs. For example, for this dates:

- 2016-10-09 (getting Sunday) (it's a Sunday)
- 2016-10-10 (getting Friday) (it's a Monday)

**The code:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String[] days = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
        String date1 = "**2016-10-09**";
        String date2 = "**2016-10-10**";
        Date d1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-Mm-Dd").parse( date1 );
        Date d2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-Mm-Dd").parse( date2 );
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(d1);
        String day1 = days[cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)-1];
        cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(d2);
        String day2 = days[cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)-1];
        System.out.printf(date1+" "+day1+"\n"+date2+" "+day2);
    }
}
```

**The Output:**

> 2016-10-09 Sunday
>
> 2016-10-10 Friday

### **Why Friday? The day after Sunday is Monday!**

Comment: Why are you using `Mm` in your format string? That may be related to the problem - it should be `MM`. I suggest you print out `d1` and `d2`... they may well not be what you think at all.

Comment: yes that's it your problem is related to your pattern it should be `yyyy-MM-dd`

Comment: Yup, just tried it - and changing your format string to `yyyy-MM-dd` fixes it. Always be careful with format strings, and always dump information as close to the parsing result as possible - in this case printing out `d1` and `d2`. (In this case, they were in January and December... so the problem has nothing to do with "getting the day of a week from a `Date`" reall.)

Comment: Thanks, that helped!. Please post a answer so that i can retrieve your effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the formatter string to **yyyy-MM-dd** and days array to start with **sunday**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String[] days = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
        String date1 = "2016-10-09";
        String date2 = "2016-10-10";
        Date d1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse( date1 );
        Date d2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse( date2 );
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(d1);

        String day1 = days[cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)-1];
        System.out.printf(date1+" "+day1+"\n");
        cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(d2);
        String day2 = days[cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)-1];
        System.out.printf(date1+" "+day1+"\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, the order of the **days of the week in `Calendar` vary** depending on the `Locale`. So you must start your array of a day-of-week strings to match the order defined in the Locale used at runtime. Better yet, avoid the mess that is `java.util.Calendar`, and use the java.time classes instead.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( "2016-10-10" )
         .getDayOfWeek()  
         .getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.US )
```

> Monday

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/ryHec1).

## *java.time*

You are using old date-time classes, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. Much simpler with the modern classes.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy.]

**No need to specify a formatting pattern**, as you input complies with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard used by default in the java.time classes. This avoids the problem in your original code of incorrect parsing.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2016-10-10" ) ;
```

The [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum defines seven objects, one for each day of the week. Use these in your code instead of numbers or strings.

```
DayOfWeek dow = ld.getDayOfWeek();
```

Ask for a [localized name of the day](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#getDisplayName-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Locale-).

```
String output = dow.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.US );  // Or Locale.CANADA_FRENCH etc.
```

### Full example

Parse each of the two dates in question.

```
LocalDate ld09 = LocalDate.parse( "2016-10-09" ) ;
LocalDate ld10 = LocalDate.parse( "2016-10-10" ) ;
```

Generate a display name of each date’s day-of-week.

```
String output09 = ld09 + " | " + 
    ld09.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.US ) ;
String output10 = ld10 + " | " + 
    ld10.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.US ) ;
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( output09 );
System.out.println( output10 );
```

> 2016-10-09 | Sunday
>
> 2016-10-10 | Monday

For fun, same thing in Canada French.

```
String output10_Québec = ld10 + " | " + 
    ld10.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH  ) ;
```

> 2016-10-10 | lundi

See [this code in action in ideone.com](http://ideone.com/7NumCj).

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).